# Grid Table VIew

Tags: iphone

IN my application I m using UITABleView in grid format which contain 16 columns .

So my query is I want horizontal scroll bar inn UITAble view and how to apply it in codes.

Please send me necessary code for it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well, you said please, but that still doesn't cut it.

Comment: Where do I email the finished product?

Answer (score 0):

Before loading a table view, load a scroll view with content size as per your requirement, and set delegate self to scroll view, 
Now add your table view to scroll view and enable horizontal and vertical scroll.
There your problem rectifies and enjoy your coding..